# Python and regex - search in file

Tags: python, regex

Assume I have some text in *.txt file:

```
NUM_SITE_CHAINS 1
SITE_DESCR EVIDENCE_CODE: SOFTWARE BINDING  FOR RESIDUE ZN A 179
NUMBER_OF_AA 4 22
EXPOSURE   0.45   0.26
DISCONTINUITY 18.000
SITE -3.275 0.375 -0.525 0.125 44.400 57.400 44.725 21.700
ENVIRONMENT 0.718 -0.232 0.138 0.000 40.164 28.782 55.655 42.505
```

I want to find line starting with "SITE" In my example it will be 6-th line. I don't want to find the second line because there is no space after "SITE". To do that I tried something like this:

```
with open(fname) as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if re.search(r"^SITE\s", part):
                listSITE.append(line)
```

But the "listSITE" remain empty. Is there a problem with regex expression or in inappropriate re. method? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you might not need the second `for` loop and change the if condition to `if re.search(r"^SITE\s", line):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(fname) as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if line.startswith('SITE '):
            listSITE.append(line)
```

No need to import re, just use startswith (note the space at the end of the SITE str.

Comment: Works great! Moreover - code looks simpler! Many thanks!

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall`, with the pattern `^SITE .*$`:

```
input = "..."
lines = re.findall(r'^SITE .*$', input, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(lines)

['SITE -3.275 0.375 -0.525 0.125 44.400 57.400 44.725 21.700']
```

Comment: that also catches AAAA SITE BBBB should only catch starting with, the previous version with the french accent in the beggining was correct